# mysql ignoring NULL while using group by and where condition

Tags: mysql, null, group-by

I am able to replicate my issue with a very simple case..
**Explanation**
I have a very simple table `my_table` with one column `column1`.

```
create table my_table (column1 varchar(58));
```

I have few values for this column, `NULL` is also one of them.

```
insert into my_table (column1) values ('value1'), ('value1'), ('value2'), (null), ('value2');
```

**Problem**
When I try to query for  `group by column1` It is giving expected results by grouping all `NULL`s together. However if I add a `where` clause on `column1` something like

```
select count(1) as value_count, column1 from my_table where column1 <> 'value1' group by column1;
```

It is ignoring both `value1` and `NULL` where I was expecting to ignore only `value1`.

With this simple case I could get a workaround for this by adding an `OR` condition, But it is a real pain to add this condition all over in my original case.

Could someone can explain me better why this behavior and how can I fix this?

Comment: Could the downvoter please leave an explanation, so that the OP can improve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because any comparison with a NULL does not produce a true or false result, but instead produces a NULL result. Consequently, the condition `column1 <> 'value1'` evaluates as NULL where `column1` is NULL, and so NULL values are not selected.

You can get around this by using a function such as `coalesce` to test `column1` - like so:

```
select count(1) as value_count, column1 
from my_table 
where coalesce(column1,'') <> 'value1' 
group by column1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Null means "a value, but I don't know what it is".

So is `column1 <> 'value1'`? If column1 is null, then "Is a value, but I don't know what it is, unequal to 'value1'"?

Clearly the answer is "I don't know. I don't know what the value is".

The only rows included by a where clause are those which pass the `where` clause test. We don't know if this row passes the test, so it will not be included in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making use of the MySQL [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) in your predicate:

```
select count(1) as value_count, column1 from my_table where ifnull(column1,'nullvalue') <> 'value1' group by column1;
```

Comment: Check out Ben's answer above for "why this behaviour". No point repeating!

Comment: Not repeated bro! Check the timestamp of comment and answer.